# Configurar Rota WebForms ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, route

Boa tarde, tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET em WebForms (ainda) funcionando normalmente, o cliente pediu para incluir a data na rota de uma nova pagina, criei a rota assim:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute(
         "RevendaMapRoute",
         "Revendas/{data}/{idnome}",
         "~/Revendas.aspx", false,null,
          new RouteValueDictionary { {"data", @"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"},{ "idnome", "[a-z0-9 -]*" } });´´´´
```

No Page_load .cs recupero a URL assim:

```
            var rt = RouteData.Route as Route;
            if (rt != null && rt.Url == "Revendas/{data}/{idnome}")
            {}´´
```

A chamada para a rota:

```
<a href='<%#: GetRouteUrl("RevendaMapRoute", new { data = Item.DATA, idnome = Item.NOME_REVENDA_ROUTE}) %>'><%#: Item.NOME_REVENDA %></a>´´
```

O quando clico no link o retorno é 404 pagina não existente... Acredito que a barra normal '/' na data não esteja identificando a rota corretamente, pois como disse sem a data na rota funciona normalmente. Grato por qualquer ajuda.